¿Como obtener los hijos inmediatos utilizando querySelectorAll?
Estoy desarrollando una tabla donde muestro un listado de productos, donde algunos de estos productos son combos. Estos combos estan formados por 2 o mas productos.
Necesito obtener solo las filas hijas de la tabla desde la que estoy buscando.
Por ejemplo:


const tabla = document.getElementById('tabla'),
  filas = tabla.querySelectorAll('tbody>tr');

console.log([...filas]);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.text_center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text_right {
  text-align: right;
}
<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50px">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th class="text_right" width="100px">Precio U.</th>
      <th class="text_right" width="100px">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="text_right" width="100px">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text_center"><button type="button" data-action="remove">X</button></td>
      <td colspan="4" style="padding:0">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5" class="text_center">COMBO X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="90px"><img src="/img/item1.png" width="80" /></td>
              <td>Producto 1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$10</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">2</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="90px"><img src="/img/item2.png" width="80" /></td>
              <td>Producto 1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$5</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$5</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text_center"><button type="button" data-action="remove">X</button></td>
      <td colspan="4" style="padding:0">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="90px"><img src="/img/item3.png" width="80" /></td>
              <td>Producto 3</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">2</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



En el ejemplo me devuelve 6 filas pero yo solo quiero las 2 filas que estan en el tbody hijo de tabla
Probe usando querySelectorAll('>tbody>tr') pero me da error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '>tbody>tr' is not a valid selector.

¿Se puede lograr utilizando querySelectorAll?

Una solución es utilizando la pseudo clase :scope:

La pseudo clase CSS :scope representa elementos que son un punto de referencia, o scope, para que los selectores puedan compararlos.
[...]
Cuando se utiliza dentro de una llamada a la API DOM, como querySelector(), querySelectorAll(), matches() o Element.closest(), :scope coincide con el elemento sobre el que se ha llamado al método.
Traducción libre

Ejemplo:


const tabla = document.getElementById('tabla'),
  filas = tabla.querySelectorAll(':scope>tbody>tr');

console.log([...filas]);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.text_center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text_right {
  text-align: right;
}
<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50px">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th class="text_right" width="100px">Precio U.</th>
      <th class="text_right" width="100px">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="text_right" width="100px">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="child">
      <td class="text_center"><button type="button" data-action="remove">X</button></td>
      <td colspan="4" style="padding:0">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5" class="text_center">COMBO X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="90px"><img src="/img/item1.png" width="80" /></td>
              <td>Producto 1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$10</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">2</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="90px"><img src="/img/item2.png" width="80" /></td>
              <td>Producto 1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$5</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$5</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
      <td class="text_center"><button type="button" data-action="remove">X</button></td>
      <td colspan="4" style="padding:0">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="90px"><img src="/img/item3.png" width="80" /></td>
              <td>Producto 3</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$1</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">2</td>
              <td class="text_right" width="100px">$2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



PD: Agregue a las filas hijas class="child" solo para demostrar/visualizar que son exactamente las filas hijas. Se puede sacar sin problema.

El error al usar tbody>tr no consideró la jerarquía de anidamiento de la tabla.
Al analizar las tablas anidadas en la estructura del HTML, el <tr> del tbody de la tabla tiene otra tabla que también tiene <tbody>.
Cuando usaste tbody>tr no va a hacer distinción entre el tbody de la tabla principal y los tbody de las tablas anidadas.
<tbody>
  <tr> <!--principal -->
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:0">
      <table> <!-- mesa anidada -->
        <tbody>
          <tr> <!-- linea interior  1 -->
            <td>Producto 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> <!-- linea interior 2 -->
            <td>Producto 2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

Puedes hacerlo de forma separada
const tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
const tbody = tabla.querySelector('tbody');
const filas = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

console.log(filas);

Otra forma de resolverlo es usando children junto con el método forEach del prototipo de Array sobre el HTMLCollection
const tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
const tbody = tabla.querySelector('tbody');
const filas = [];


Array.prototype.forEach.call(tbody.children, function(child) {
  if (child.tagName === 'TR') {
    filas.push(child);
  }
});

console.log(filas);

